# Why does my command run twice in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

## Take a look at this basic moderation command:

```
@client.command(name="purge", aliases= ["clear"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount=2):
    delete_embed=discord.Embed(title="Messages Purged", description=f"You have cleared the past {amount} messages!", color=discord.Color.green())
    delete_embed.set_footer(text=f"Cleared by {ctx.author.name}")
    amount += 1
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(embed=delete_embed, delete_after=5)
```

So what are we doing here? Well when someone with the 'manage messages' permission uses this command, we define a 'delete_embed' and we add '1' to the amount that person wants to delete. So when someone uses this command:

```
b/clear 2    # prefix is 'b/'
```

Then 3 messages including the user's message will delete and the 'delete_embed' will be sent to the channel. But why is the embed sent TWICE? And why does the bot delete ANOTHER 2 messages? Maybe this command is not the issue, so here is an EVENT + a LISTENER that my code includes that may help you people help me:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    try:
        if msg.mentions[0] == client.user:
            with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
                prefixes = json.load(f)
            pre = prefixes[str(msg.guild.id)]
            
            pinged_embed=discord.Embed(title="The good Bot", description=" This bot was designed completely and solely for me!", color=discord.Color.green())
            pinged_embed.add_field(name=f"PREFIX SET: '{pre}'", value=f"Use {pre} setprefix to change it")
            pinged_embed.add_field(name=f"VERSION:", value="v0.68.2")

            await msg.channel.send(embed=pinged_embed)
    except:
        pass
    await client.process_commands(msg)  


@client.listen()
async def on_message(msg):

    for word in filtered_words:
        if word.lower() in msg.content: #.lower() for making it case insensitive
            await msg.delete()
            await msg.channel.send("Mind your language!")
            return
    await client.process_commands(msg)
```

Otherwise nothing else really... Do you know what the issue is? Does it have anything to do with my on_message events? Would appreciate some help, Thanks

Comment: I can see why calling ```client.process_commands(msg)``` from an event and a listener produces the output twice.
You can just remove the ```await client.process_commands(msg)```  from the ```@client.listen()``` but I would have only one ```on_message``` defined

Answer (score 1):

Just pack all the code inside the client event and remove @client.listen()

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word.lower() in msg.content: #.lower() for making it case insensitive
            await msg.delete()
            await msg.channel.send("Mind your language!")
            return
    try:
        if msg.mentions[0] == client.user:
            with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
                prefixes = json.load(f)
            pre = prefixes[str(msg.guild.id)]
            
            pinged_embed=discord.Embed(title="The good Bot", description=" This bot was designed completely and solely for me!", color=discord.Color.green())
            pinged_embed.add_field(name=f"PREFIX SET: '{pre}'", value=f"Use {pre} setprefix to change it")
            pinged_embed.add_field(name=f"VERSION:", value="v0.68.2")

            await msg.channel.send(embed=pinged_embed)
    except:
        pass
    await client.process_commands(msg)
```

You can use listen() to listen to new messages with several functions but you should only process the command and send the answer once

Answer (score 1):

do you have any cogs? this happened to me once and it was because I put

```
await client.process_commands(message)
```

in my cog on_message event too, causing the bot to run the commands found twice